# Python, отправка письма через mail.ru

Tags: python, email, smtp

Учусь...
Пишу код по отправке письма с mail.ru

Если вставлять текст письма в код напрямую, то работает

```py
smtp_server.sendmail(email_sender,email_getter, "Привет")
```

Если вставлять текст письма в код через переменную, то нет

```py
msg="Привет"
smtp_server.sendmail(email_sender,email_getter, msg)
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
File "C:\ProgLesson\pythonProject\main.py", line 19, in <module>
    smtp_server.sendmail(email_sender,email_getter, msg) #отправка сообщения
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\smtplib.py", line 864, in sendmail
    msg = _fix_eols(msg).encode('ascii')
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Я понимаю, что он ругается на кодировку (русский язык), но как это победить-то?

Comment: Переведите кодировку в UTF-8. `msg = _fix_eols(msg).encode('utf-8')`

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что у вас в `msg` на самом деле не `"Привет"`